# Sphinx installation error

Tags: shell, ssh, centos, sphinx

I'm trying to install Sphinx on my CentOS 6.5 VPS and get the following error.

```
root@hen [~]# yum localinstall sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
Marking sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.adams.net
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * updates: mirrors.bluehost.com
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
hgdedi                                                   | 2.5 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sphinx.x86_64 0:2.1.7-1.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.4.20-1.el6_5 will be installed
---> Package sphinx.x86_64 0:2.1.7-1.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-12.el6_3 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64 (/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64 (/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
```

I'm more or less lost when it comes to shell commands so I hope someone can guide me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

first, should sort it.